# How can I convert .lrprev in .jpeg?

Tags: backup, adobe-lightroom

I broke a hard drive but I notice that the pictures in the catalog have been saved in the

- C:\Users\Vyrus\Pictures\Lightroom\LightR ... 3 Catalog Previews.lrdata.

they are in a format other than .jpeg (they are .lrprev)

What can I do?

Comment: See: [Is there a way to export Lightroom's thumbnails whatever the resolution they are?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/is-there-a-way-to-export-lightrooms-thumbnails-whatever-the-resolution-they-are)

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information, or just post a comment. Have you looked at the link I gave you? BitmapRip can export pictures from `.lrprev` files.

Answer (score 2):

follow this instructions :
http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/extract-previews-lightroom-4.html

... to get and install the script called "extract previews" which will allow you to convert your saved previews as jpg.

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems straight forward:

1. Open them in lightroom. (Free download [here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop_lightroom))
2. Save them as jpeg.

However that might be to trivial.

Are there really pictures in there? Or are you looking at previews?

Comment: when i open the preview in lightroom i can't use the command "export" and aloft there's a notice: "the file called ... is offline or missing"

Comment: It might be useful to add that to the original post.

Comment: @Andrea That's because the original files are in fact missing. Do you still have them or were they destroyed with the hard drive? The `.lrprev` files are just previews, but Lightroom depends on the originals to be there.

Comment: they destroyed with the hard drive. have i to give up?

Comment: Yes. Get a new harddrive. Install a new OS and optionally a fresh install os lightroom. Then restore as much as you can from backups (assuming you have them).